# Render on the "dark side of the moon" using d3-geo

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geo

Using the orthographic projection in d3-geo I'd like to be able to render points on the invisible side of the projected sphere. Specifically, I'm making an animation where a train of points travels around a meridian, but when they reach the edge, it's as if they fall off (until they reach the other side, of course). Please see my code snippet below.

Currently, the path generator (`path` in my example) simply returns `null` if you try to evaluate it on a point that's hidden. This is of course what it's supposed to do, but is it possible to tweak it such that it gives me the equivalent point on the front surface, such that I can render it in a lighter color so that it's as if we're looking through the sphere?

```js
let width = 400;
let points = [...Array(20).keys()].map(k => 2 * k).map(k => [k, 50]);

let svg = d3.select("#d3-example")
  .attr("height", 400)
  .attr("width", width)
  .style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges");

let projection = d3.geoOrthographic()
  .rotate([0, -30])

projection
  .translate([width / 2, 150])
  .scale(width / 960 * projection.scale())

let path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", path(d3.geoGraticule10()))
  .attr("stroke", "#AAAAAA")
  .attr("stroke-width", 0.5)
  .attr("fill", "none");

let pt = svg.append("g")
  .attr("id", "loc-points")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(points)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", d => path(convertPointToGeoJSON(d)))
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("fill", "black")
  .attr("opacity", (d, i) => (i + 1) / 20)
  .attr("stroke-width", 1)

pt.transition()
  .duration(5000)
  .ease(d3.easeLinear)
  .on("start", function repeat() {
    d3.active(this)
      .attrTween("d", d => {
        return t => {
          return pointpos(t)(d)
        }
      })
      .transition()
      .on("start", repeat)
  })

function pointpos(t) {
  return function(d) {
    return path(convertPointToGeoJSON([d[0] + 360 * t, d[1]]))
  }
}

function convertPointToGeoJSON(point) {
  return {
    type: "Point",
    coordinates: [point[0], point[1]]
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="d3-example"></svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very lazy and silly way to do that is just creating another projection without clipping anything (using `projection.clipAngle(0)`), and then changing the stroke and fill according to your original projection.

Here's a demo (I'm moving the circles closer to the equator, so it's easier to see the them on the hidden side):

```js
let width = 400;
let points = [...Array(20).keys()].map(k => 2 * k).map(k => [k, 20]);

let svg = d3.select("#d3-example")
  .attr("height", 400)
  .attr("width", width)
  .style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges");

let projection = d3.geoOrthographic()
  .rotate([0, -30])

let projection2 = d3.geoOrthographic()
  .rotate([0, -30])
  .clipAngle(0)

projection
  .translate([width / 2, 150])
  .scale(width / 960 * projection.scale())

projection2
  .translate([width / 2, 150])
  .scale(width / 960 * projection2.scale())

let path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);
let path2 = d3.geoPath().projection(projection2);

svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", path(d3.geoGraticule10()))
  .attr("stroke", "#AAAAAA")
  .attr("stroke-width", 0.5)
  .attr("fill", "none");

let pt = svg.append("g")
  .attr("id", "loc-points")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(points)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", d => path2(convertPointToGeoJSON(d)))
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("fill", "black")
  .attr("opacity", (d, i) => (i + 1) / 20)
  .attr("stroke-width", 1)

pt.transition()
  .duration(5000)
  .ease(d3.easeLinear)
  .on("start", function repeat() {
    d3.active(this)
      .styleTween("fill", d => {
        return t => {
          return pointpos(t)(d) ? "black" : "#ccc"
        }
      })
      .styleTween("stroke", d => {
        return t => {
          return pointpos(t)(d) ? "black" : "#aaa"
        }
      })
      .attrTween("d", d => {
        return t => {
          return pointpos2(t)(d)
        }
      })
      .transition()
      .on("start", repeat)
  })

function pointpos(t) {
  return function(d) {
    return path(convertPointToGeoJSON([d[0] + 360 * t, d[1]]))
  }
}

function pointpos2(t) {
  return function(d) {
    return path2(convertPointToGeoJSON([d[0] + 360 * t, d[1]]))
  }
}

function convertPointToGeoJSON(point) {
  return {
    type: "Point",
    coordinates: [point[0], point[1]]
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="d3-example"></svg>
```

I'm sure someone will post a proper solution soon.

Comment: I think this is the proper solution, it was what I was typing before you got there. I'd suggest setting the clip angle to 180 for a more explicit and clear value to show the whole world though.  The main alternative I can think of would be to use a single clip angle of 180 and then do the math to see if the point is visible or not and style accordingly, that's got to be a lot less fun given an arbitrary rotation and pathing.